# how to show Edit and Delete buttons if date equals today only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I show EDIT and DELETE buttons in an ASP.NET MVC view only if date equals today, and hide it if it's not today's date?

I tried the following :

```
@{ 
    string Today = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}

@if (Today == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
{
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
    </td>
}
else
{
}
```

but it's showing them always, and does not hide the buttons.

How to do that please?

EDIT :

I have order date and I need to compare the order date if equals today's date then show edit and delete buttons if order date less than today date then hide buttons and not allowed to edit and delete this is the view code :

```
@model IEnumerable<warehouse.Models.STATISTICS_DAILY>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<h2>Hospital Statistics</h2>

@{
    DateTime Today = DateTime.Today;
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SAMPLES_MORNING)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SAMPLES_EVENING)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TESTS_MORNING)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DATE)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.stat_Departments.Dept_name)
        </th>
        @*<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sys_users.user_name)
        </th>*@
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hospital.hospital_name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sys_users1.user_name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SAMPLES_MORNING)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SAMPLES_EVENING)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TESTS_MORNING)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TESTS_EVENING)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.stat_Departments.Dept_name)
        </td>
        @*<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sys_users.user_name)
        </td>*@
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hospital.hospital_name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sys_users1.user_name)
        </td>
         @if (Today.Date == Model.FirstOrDefault().DATE)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        }
        else
        {

        }

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I tried this  `@if (Today.Date == Model.FirstOrDefault().DATE)`
its hided the buttons for all orders dates and not show if order date equals today

this is the model

This is the model class

```
public partial class STATISTICS_DAILY
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DEPT_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SAMPLES_MORNING { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SAMPLES_EVENING { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TESTS_MORNING { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TESTS_EVENING { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> hospital_no { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> user_id { get; set; }

    public virtual stat_Departments stat_Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual sys_users sys_users { get; set; }
    public virtual Hospital Hospital { get; set; }
    public virtual sys_users sys_users1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using **strings** to compare dates? Just use the actual **date** value directly! `DateTime today = DateTime.Today` (use `.Today` instead of `.Now` which includes the time portion as well). Then `@if (Today == DateTime.Today) ......`

Comment: With the code you have, it's always comparing today with today. What's your actual date source?

Comment: @Ouroborus actually I have order Date I need to compare if order date equals today then I need to update or delete if order date less than today date I need to hide buttons only allow edit or delete for orders created today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **date values** to compare - don't always convert everything to strings for no good reason.....

Also, use `DateTime.Today` to get today's date without the time portion - otherwise, you're comparing milliseconds and those might differ.

And lastly, refer to the `.Date` property to get just the date (no time) for your comparison.

Try this:

```
@{ 
    DateTime Today = DateTime.Today;
}

@if (Today.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
{
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
    </td>
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: thank you sir this code working but it show for all orders dates I need to compare with order DATE if order date equals today date then show buttons if less than today date then hide the buttons how to do it please I added more details to question?

Comment: I added this code  @if (Today.Date == Model.FirstOrDefault().DATE) but also it hided buttons and not show for today date also

Comment: Try this: `@if (Today.Date == Item.DATE.Date) ....` - that should work ... you need to reference the **current** `item` you're binding - not just an arbitrary (first) entry in your "Model" enumeration ....

Comment: thank you so much this one working    @if (Today.Date == item.DATE.Value.Date)  :)